# Codeigniter library class public variables not working

Tags: php, class, codeigniter, variables

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
<?php

if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class sample{

function __construct() {
    $this->ci = & get_instance();
    }

public $name;
public $style;


function set_data($data)
{
    /* List of parameters that you can set */

    $this->name = (isset($data['name']) ? $data['name']: ''); // Set select name
    $this->style = (isset($data['style']) ? $data['style']: ''); // Set select style

}

function select_both_dropdown()
{
    $select = '<select name="'.$this->name.'" class="chzn-select" style="'.$this->style.'">';
    $select .= '<option value=""></option>';
    $select .= '</select>';
return $select;
}
```

Controller:

```
$data['select'] = $this->sample->select_both_dropdown(array(
        'name' => 'eventselect',
        'style' => 'min-width: 247px;'
    ));
```

How it is being loaded in controller:
    function _*construct() {
        parent::*_construct();
        $this->load->library('tank_auth');
        $this->load->library('sample');
    }

When the select loads on the screen, nothing is filled in.  No name, no style etc..  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference them properly;

In the library;

```
// as you have done
$this->select = 'foo';
```

In your controller it would be something like `$this->sample->name` or `$this->sample->style`

But the $select is not an attribute or being returned so will not be avaiable.

UPDATE - based on comments
controller;

```
$this->sample->set_data(array(
        'name' => 'eventselect',
        'style' => 'min-width: 247px;'
    ));
$data['select'] = $this->sample->select_both_dropdown();
```

**ANOTHER UPDATE**:

```
function select_both_dropdown($data)
{
    $this->set_data($data);
    $select = '<select name="'.$this->name.'" class="chzn-select" style="'.$this->style.'">';
    $select .= '<option value=""></option>';
    $select .= '</select>';
return $select;
}
```

I would then change set_data() to private instead of public.

Comment: This is a custom library, the select menu is being built in the library via parameters passed by the controller.

Comment: Then modify your library according to what Rooneyl said.

Comment: $select is returned outside of the function

Comment: how are you calling the library in your controller?

Comment: you never call set_data, so the attributes will be empty, see answer update

Comment: How do I do that in the select_both_dropdown function

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11648/discussion-between-rooneyl-and-k-g)